# Referencing a cell value in VBA that contains "%"

Tags: string, excel, vba

I'm trying to reference a cell in VBA that contains the character "%" as a part of it, which is causing a *Type mismatch* error. I need the character to be there, because the values will later be copied to a SQL query. Is there a way to make VBA get the value of that cell without giving me the error?

Here is the code:

> Dim namevalue As Variant
>   namevalue = Sheets("Sheetname").Range("N4").Value
>   With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").OLEDBConnection 
>           .BackgroundQuery = True
>           .CommandText = Array( _
>           "SELECT ""COMPANY"".""PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME"" WHERE ""COMPANY"".""PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME"" like " & namevalue)
>       End With  
>       With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection")
>       End With
>       ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").Refresh
>   End Sub

The content of cell N4 is the following:

> ('%CROSSJECT%' or COMPANY.PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME like '%FLUOR CORP%' or COMPANY.PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME like '%HITIT HOLD%' or COMPANY.PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME like '%LARAMIDE R%' or COMPANY.PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME like '%LARAMIDE R%' or COMPANY.PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME like '%MAGNUM ENT%'))

UPDATE: I don't think the error is related to the character anymore, but the error persists.

I appreciate any help with this.
Thanks!

Comment: Is that your actual code?  What's the value in N4 ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the character that causes the error. What's going on in the part of the code which starts with `Array`?

Comment: What is the actual question here? Is it how to get hold of a cell containing the `#` hash?

Comment: @Tim Willians - the cell value in N4 right now is `'like '%CROSSJECT%' or COMPANY.PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME like '%FLUOR CORP%' or COMPANY.PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME like '%HITIT HOLD%' or COMPANY.PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME like '%LARAMIDE R%' or COMPANY.PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME like '%LARAMIDE R%'))`

Comment: @Kapol - the array portion of the code is what I posted, and I think the error is caused by what's in the cell, because if I reference a different cell, I don't get the same error...

Comment: @mehow I think the question is just how to get Excel to reference the cell without giving the the _type mismatch_ error. I thought the problem was with some of my characters, but I think that has been ruled out.

Comment: @Kapol I just realized I had left out a little piece of the code. Here is the Array function as I have it: `Array( _
"SELECT ""COMPANY"".""PRIMARY_LONG_COMPANY_NAME"" WHERE ""SECURITY_CROSS_REF"".""SECURITY_ID_VALUE"" in " & namevalue)`

Comment: Your post title is causing some confusion - it says "#" but your question is about "%"  You should update your question with the **full code** - just a couple of snippets are not useful in trying to resolve the issue.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm sorry about the confusion. I edited the title to reflect the change, and I also posted the whole code and cell content. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try running that SQL directly in a query tool - does it error?  And I don't think you need to wrap the string in an Array.

Comment: @TimWilliams It worked! For some reason, not wrapping it up in an Array did the trick, even though I have other queries set up like this using the Array function.

Answer (score 0):

To reference the cell, you need to locate it.  Try this small macro:

```
Sub PoundFinder()
    Dim Pound As String
    Pound = "#"
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(1, v, Pound) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Pound found in cell " & r.Address
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox Pound & " not found"
End Sub
```